# Inequality regarding quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $Q_n(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)=\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}x_ix_j$ be a positive definite quadratic form and let $D_{n-1}(x2 ,x3 , …..xn) =Q_n(0,x_2 ,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$. Prove that the inequality    $D_n \leq a_{11}D_{n-1}$ holds for the discriminant of the form.In a text book of vector and matrices I have found the problem and as a hint it was instructed  to use the Cauchy expansion of Dn. I know that the Cauchy expansion of detA  is 
              $$DetA =a_{11}A_{11}-\sum\sum a_{i1}a_{1j}A_{11;ij}$$
$A_{11;ij}$  denotes the cofactor of $a_{ij}$ in $A_{11}$ but can not proceed further.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your math text. This link may be a useful reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference